# Web browsing history on router. How do you keep it private

Tags: router

So I purchased a new asus router and installed merlin firmware. Lots of cool features. I was checking the web history on the router and I was suprised how it listed each website my devices visited. I have ipvanish and airvpn and use epic browser, etc., and always thought that my history would be hidden, but if my router can see sites I visit, then what about at work! They can see everything, including our mac and device info.

What can you do to keep this info. from showing up on a router?

Comment: Are you sure your VPN is connected? Are you using a the Windows client on ipvanish?

Comment: Also, is your DNS being routed down the VPN?

Comment: I am running IPVanish on a surface. Router also has IPVanish running. Has leak detection on in vpn settings.

Answer (score 0):

Use Tor if you want to make it hard for anyone to see what sites you're browsing. It may not be 100% perfect, but it probably makes it too expensive for anyone to track you down unless you're an enemy of the state and/or running a darknet market for illicit stuff.

Use a private VPN service if you want to hide what sites you're hitting from your router and your home ISP and your work, but only if you don't mind that your VPN provider can see what sites you're hitting. They could still get subpoena'd and hopefully they don't keep logs, but if they're forced to start tracking user activity they could still see what sites you're hitting and they know your billing info, so they could put it together.

If you don't even want a VPN provider to see what you're browsing, you've got to use Tor.

Comment: He mentioned he already uses a VPN. I'm guessing a mobile device is leaking with an incorrect setup.

Comment: No, its a surface with ipvanish running. Router is running ipvanish too. I am not visiting sites that are suspect. I just like to test new software and value my privacy.